# TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, sqlite

I work with the sqlite3 database. An error occurs in the last line - cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?);", playe, leve, balance)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect("Stats.db")
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player(
    name TEXT,
    cash INT,
    level INT
)""")
connect.commit()

playe = input("Name: ")
balance = 10
leve = 0
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?);", playe, leve, balance)
```

Comment: You need to package your parameters in a tuple: `(playe, leve, balance)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tuple

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?);", (playe, leve, balance))
```

I saw you wrote that the data is not inserted, you can do as follows to solve this:

```
connect.commit()
connect.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `cursor.execute` you need to pass the values as a tuple or list (or any iterator).

You can do so by simply replacing `playe, leve, balance` with `(playe, leve, balance)`.

Full line:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO player VALUES(?,?,?);", (playe, leve, balance))
```